# Scala: Regex Pattern Matching

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

I have the following input strings

```
"/horses/c132?XXX=abc-049@companyorg"
"/Goats/b-01?XXX=abc-721@"
"/CATS/001?XXX=abc-451@CompanyOrg"
```

I'd like to obtain the following as output

```
"horses", "c132", "abc-049@companyorg"
"Goats", "b-01", "abc-721@"
"CATS", "001", "abc-451@CompanyOrg"
```

I tried the following

**StandardTokenParsers**

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical._
val p = new StandardTokenParsers {
 lexical.reserved ++= List("/", "?", "XXX=")
 def p = "/" ~ opt(ident) ~ "/" ~ opt(ident) ~ "?" ~ "XXX=" ~ opt(ident)
}
p: scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical.StandardTokenParsers{def p: this.Parser[this.~[this.~[this.~[String,Option[String]],String],Option[String]]]} = $anon$1@6ca97ddf

scala> p.p(new p.lexical.Scanner("/horses/c132?XXX=abc-049@companyorg"))
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
res3: p.ParseResult[p.~[p.~[p.~[String,Option[String]],String],Option[String]]] =
[1.1] failure: ``/'' expected but ErrorToken(illegal character) found

/horses/c132?XXX=abc-049@companyorg
^
```

**RegEx**

```
import scala.util.matching.regex
val p1 = "(/)(.*)(/)(.*)(?)(XXX)(=)(.*)".r
p1: scala.util.matching.Regex = (/)(.*)(/)(.*)(?)(XXX)(=)(.*)

scala> val p1(_,animal,_,id,_,_,_,company) = "/horses/c132?XXX=abc-049@companyorg"
scala.MatchError: /horses/c132?XXX=abc-049@companyorg (of class java.lang.String)
  ... 32 elided
```

Can someone please help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern looks like `/(desired-group1)/(desired-group2)?XXX=(desired-group3)`.

So, regex would be

```
scala> val extractionPattern = """(/)(.*)(/)(.*)(\?XXX=)(.*)""".r
extractionPattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = (/)(.*)(/)(.*)(\?XXX=)(.*)
```

***note*** - escape `?` char.

How it is going to work is,

```
Full match  `/horses/c132?XXX=abc-049@companyorg`
Group 1.    `/`
Group 2.    `horses`
Group 3.    `/`
Group 4.    `c132`
Group 5.    `?XXX=`
Group 6.    `abc-049@companyorg`
```

Now, apply the regex which gives you the group of all matches

```
scala> extractionPattern.findAllIn("""/horses/c132?XXX=abc-049@companyorg""")
                        .matchData.flatMap{m => m.subgroups}.toList
res15: List[String] = List(/, horses, /, c132, ?XXX=, abc-049@companyorg)
```

Since you only care care about 2nd, 4th and 6th match, only collect those.

**So the solution would look like,**

```
scala> extractionPattern.findAllIn("""/horses/c132?XXX=abc-049@companyorg""")
                        .matchData.map(_.subgroups)
                        .flatMap(matches => Seq(matches(1), matches(3), matches(4))).toList
res16: List[String] = List(horses, c132, ?XXX=)
```

**When your input does not match regex, you get empty result**

```
scala> extractionPattern.findAllIn("""/horses/c132""")
                        .matchData.map(_.subgroups)
                        .flatMap(matches => Seq(matches(1), matches(3), matches(4))).toList
res17: List[String] = List()
```

*Working regex here - https://regex101.com/r/HuGRls/1/*